# PHP can't use function with query from another php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have simple php script but from some reason when i call getUserRoles function from another script i get **"Undefined variable: mysqli"** as you can see i included dbConnect script. (Path is 1000% correct)

```
<?php

require_once '../dbConnect.php';


function getUserRoles() {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ur.roleName from user_role as ur where ur.userId = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($roleName);

    $roles = array();

    $stmt->bind_result($roleName);

    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $roles[] = $roleName;
    }

    return $roles;
}
?>
```

And from this script i want to call getUserRoles(), but when i call function i get **"Undefined variable: mysqli"** and i have no idea why, can anyone tell me where i'm making mistake ?

```
<?php
require_once '../dbConnect.php';
require_once '../security/securityService.php';

getUserRoles();

?>
```

In that script i include securityService.php script where i have getUserRoles() and i successfully make function call, but inside that function i cant connect to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because mysqli is not globalized.
Add:

```
global $mysqli;
```

under:

```
function getUserRoles() {
```

To global the `mysqli` var into the function.

Comment: It is working, but i just read that is super bad practice, can you tell me better solution for this one ?

Comment: I don't think that global a db conection it's a bad practice... But if you want you can also use: `$GLOBALS['mysqli']` to access to your mysqli var inside a function